# basic authentication with http::daemon::ssl

Tags: perl

is it possible to implement basic authentication with **http::daemon::ssl** module .

for example i want to connect from the browser to the below link with user and password :

`https://user:password@myserver.com:433/mypath?d=fd`

could this issue be implemented with HTTP::Daemon::ssl

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP::Daemon::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aDaemon%3a%3aSSL) is [HTTP::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aDaemon) with SSL support.  HTTP::Daemon doesn't do much on, it's a very basic HTTP processing server to build upon.  Fortunately, people have built upon it!  [HTTP::Daemon::App](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aDaemon%3a%3aApp) looks like what you need, it adds basic auth support.